# How to load a model using a value of an array?

Tags: magento-1.9, recurring

Using this code

```
$recurringProfile = Mage::getModel('sales/recurring_profile')->load(431);
```

I get

```
Array
(
    [profile_id] => 431
    [state] => active
    [customer_id] => 
    [store_id] => 1
    [method_code] => novalnetCc
    [created_at] => 2017-09-24 23:22:17
    [updated_at] => 2017-09-24 23:22:22
    [reference_id] => 13599300000202558
    [subscriber_name] => 
    [order_item_info] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 3234
            [quote_id] => 2897
            [created_at] => 2017-09-24 23:14:33
            [updated_at] => 2017-09-24 23:14:33
            [product_id] => 22
            [store_id] => 1
            [parent_item_id] => 
            [is_virtual] => 0
            [sku] => 1111111
            [name] => Free Test


        )
)
```

As you can see, the **order_item_info** array has **[quote_id] => 2897**. How can I load the model (or collection model) differently using the quote_id solely as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

=> just traverse the value of **quote_id**

```
Mage::getModel('specific_model_path')->load($recurringProfile['order_item_info']['quote_id'])
```

By this way you can load Model using **quote_id**